# Python Paho-Mqtt: What should I pay attention to when subscribing to more topics?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, mqtt, publish-subscribe, paho

With mqtt subscribe client I am subscribing to lots of threads (over 6000) but not getting results that change on the fly. I'm lagging. Does mqtt give possibility to subscribe too many threads in parallel in background? loop_start would that be enough?

What should I pay attention to when subscribing to more topics?

```
import logging
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import requests
import zmq
import pandas as pd

PORT=1351

def set_publisher():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket_server = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket_server.bind(f"tcp://*:{PORT}")
    return socket_server 

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #logging.warning(f"Connected with result code :: code : {rc}")
    print(f"Connected with result code :: code : {rc}")

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe(topics)

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    msg = msg.payload
    # logging.info(f"message:: {msg}\n")
    print(f"message:: {msg}\n")
    if msg:
        publisher.send(f"{msg}")

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        # logging.warning(f"Unexpected disconnection :: code: {rc}")
        print(f"Unexpected disconnection :: code: {rc}")
    #todo: if rc is change hostname raise except


client = mqtt.Client(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv31, transport="tcp")
client.username_pw_set(******, password=******)

topics = [(f"topic{i}", 0) for i in 6000]

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

if client.connect(hostname= *****, port= **** , keepalive=300) != 0:
    # logging.info("Could not connect to MQTT Broker !")
    print("Could not connect to MQTT Broker !")
    
client.loop_forever(timeout=3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a situation of compute power (either at the client or the broker or in-between) not sufficient to handle your scenario. It is a common occurrance and that is what performance testing is for: does your setup handle your scenario for your requirements? Capacity planning then expands that question to: ... in the future.